# if statement being ignored, something wrong with uint8_t

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50, uint8t

the values are given by images, so

```
typedef struct IMAGE{
        uint8_t  rgbtBlue;
        uint8_t  rgbtGreen;
        uint8_t  rgbtRed;
}IMAGE;
IMAGE image[height][width];
```

in the function, I create another 2 dimensional array.

```
typedef struct BUFFER{
        uint8_t  rgbtBlue;
        uint8_t  rgbtGreen;
        uint8_t  rgbtRed;
    }BUFFER;
BUFFER buffer[height][width];
```

After calculation, I will give the values back, updating the images' values.

But I encounter a problem. For example:

```
int GxB, GyB;
buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((double)sqrt(GxB * GxB + GyB * GyB));
if (buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue >= 255)
      buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
printf("%d\n", buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue);
```

If statement is keeping being ignored, I know there must be something wrong with uint8_t because after I change **rgbtBlue** to integer, everything is fine, the if statement is working. I've searched online but cannot find the answer. Any tips will be appreciated

Comment: `uint8_t` is already an integer. What do you mean by "change **rgbtBlue** to integer"?

Comment: `uint8_t` can never be greater than 255. If the multiplication overflows, it wraps around.

Comment: @MikeCAT He means `int`.

Comment: The range of uint8_t is 0 to 255, so your if statement is pointless.  You have already truncated the value.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value of `uint8_t` is 255. Therefore,

```
if (buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue >= 255)
      buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
```

means

```
if (buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue == 255)
      buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
```

and it does virtually nothing.

You may want to store the result of `round()` to a bigger type not to cause truncation and then check the value, do proper process and assign to `buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue` like this:

```
double round_res = round((double)sqrt(GxB * GxB + GyB * GyB));
if (round_res >= 255)
      round_res = 255;
buffer[i][j].rgbtBlue = round_res;
```